# Why code indentation or prettify added semicolon in WebStorm?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am using WebStorm in my Angular project and I'm facing an issue of semicolon  in `arrow` function.

[image]

When I removed this `semicolon` it removes this error. But in future whenever I prettify my file using <kbd>Command + Option + L</kbd> semicolon inserted in `arrow` function.

Suggest the solution

1. How I will change the TSLint setting so that it will not show error?
2. or what IntelliJ settings I need to change so that it will not add `semicolon` on prettifying or indentation?

**TSLint file**

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "arrow-return-shorthand": true,
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "deprecation": {
      "severity": "warn"
    },
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-super": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-misused-new": true,
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unnecessary-initializer": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],
    "no-output-on-prefix": true,
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
  }
}
```

Comment: It's because you're defining a Class level function (this is not exactly normal convention). Class definitions are completely contained on the parent level, and it's pretty standard across languages that these lines don't require a stop.

Comment: note that you can configure WebStorm formatter behavior in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Punctuation** by choosing `don't use semicolon to terminate statements always`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be the expected behaviour from tslint. 
You can find the related github issue here: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1476

You should be able to fix this by setting the `ignore-bound-class-methods` property.

```
"semicolon": [true, "always", "ignore-bound-class-methods"]
```